# Nuxt server route api and using Deno: How to import Deno packages using a URL?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, deno, nuxt3, nitro

What is the proper way to import packages from a URL when using Deno runtime?

I get the following error:

`ERROR  [worker reload] [worker init] Only URLs with a scheme in: file and data are supported by the default ESM loader. Received protocol 'https:'`

I get that error when trying to run this code a Nuxt server api route (using Deno):

```
import { OpenAI } from "https://deno.land/x/openai/mod.ts"; //<--- what is correct way to import this????

const systemPrompts = [...]


export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {


  const openAI = new OpenAI('<API_KEY>');

  const chatCompletion = await openAI.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: [
      { "role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant." },
      { "role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?" },
      {
        "role": "assistant",
        "content": "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020.",
      },
      { "role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?" },
    ],
  });

  console.log(chatCompletion);
})
```